# jQuery fake element hover state

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element that will show another element when mouse over it.
im doing something like:

```
if ($("#target").is(":hover")) {
  //show other element
}
```

I'm having trouble to write test for this, so #target element has hover state. I tried to fire sequence of mouse events, mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, click, etc,
but that if statement still returns false. Is there a way that I can set an element hover state?

Comment: Could you provide more code please? As it is, it's difficult to understand in what context you're running this line of code.

Comment: try using jquery-simulate. Was originally created to test all the jQuery UI widgets

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to use necessarily jQuery but I think you can try to achieve the same result with a css only solution.

Look at this example:

```css
.shown-on-hover {
  display: none;
}

.some-class:hover  .shown-on-hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-class">
Here some content always visible
  <div class="shown-on-hover">Some content</div>
</div>
```